# Scrapy: Can't login to dual-login page: onestop.jdsu.com

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

I am developing a scraper for internal use and evaluation of my company's partner website onestop.jdsu.com. The website is actually ASPX site.

I can't get scrapy to login to the page:  https://onestop.jdsu.com/_layouts/JDSU.OneStop/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F

There are actually two methods of login on the page and I think I'm having a problem with distinguishing them in the scrapy spider.  The one I'm most interested in is the "partner login" although login using the employee login, which is actually a script that displays a drop-down login window,  would be fine.

I've used "loginform" to extract the relevant fields from both forms.  Unfortunately no combination of relevant POST data seems to make a difference.  Perhaps I'm not clicking the button on the partner form ("ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$loginControl$login","")?

Also the "Login failed" message does not come through even when I know the login had to have failed.

The spider below ignores "__VIEWSTATE" and "__EVENTVALIDATION" because they don't make a difference if included and they don't seem to have anything to do with the partner login in the HTML of the page.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

---

### LOGINFORM TEST OUTPUT

```
python ./test.py https://onestop.jdsu.com/_layouts/JDSU.OneStop/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F
[1] 1273
peter-macbook:_loginform-master peter$ [
   "https://onestop.jdsu.com/_layouts/JDSU.OneStop/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F", 
   [
      [
         [
            "__VIEWSTATE", 
            "/wEPDwUKMTEzNDkwMDAxNw9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIDD2QWCAIDDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGQCBQ8WAh8AaGQCCw9kFgYCAQ8WAh4EaHJlZgUhL193aW5kb3dzL2RlZmF1bHQuYXNweD9SZXR1cm5Vcmw9ZAIDD2QWAgIDDw8WAh8AaGRkAgUPFgIfAGhkAg0PFgIfAGgWAgIBDw8WAh4ISW1hZ2VVcmwFIS9fbGF5b3V0cy8xMDMzL2ltYWdlcy9jYWxwcmV2LnBuZ2RkZP7gVj0vs2N5c/DzKfAu4DwrFihP"
         ], 
         [
            "__EVENTVALIDATION", 
            "/wEWBALlpOFKAoyn3a4JAuj7pusEAsXI9Y8HY+WYdEUkWKmn7tesA+BODBefeYE="
         ], 
         [
            "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$loginControl$UserName", 
            "USER"
         ], 
         [
            "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$loginControl$password", 
            "PASS"
         ], 
         [
            "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$loginControl$login", 
            ""
         ]
      ], 
      "https://onestop.jdsu.com/_layouts/JDSU.OneStop/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F", 
      "POST"
   ]
]
```

---

### SCRAPY SPIDER FOR PARTNER LOGIN

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import WaveReadyItem
#from scrapy import log
#from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

class WaveReadySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "onestop_home-page-3"
    allowed_domains = ["https://onestop.jdsu.com"]
    start_urls = [
                  "https://onestop.jdsu.com/_layouts/JDSU.OneStop/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F",
                  "https://onestop.jdsu.com/Products/network-systems/Pages/default.aspx"
                  ]

    def parse(self, response):
       return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
       response,
       formdata={'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$loginControl$UserName': 'MY-USERID', 'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$loginControl$password': 'MY-PASSWD',  'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$loginControl$login': ''},
       callback=self.after_login
       )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "Invalid ID or Password" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

    def parse(self, response):
    #=============================================================================
    #HOME PAGE:  PICK UP OTHER LANDING PAGES IN CENTER COLUMN
    #=============================================================================

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you fail. But here is how I use "loginform".

```
def parse(self, response):
    args, url, method = fill_login_form(response.url, response.body, self.username, self.password)
    return FormRequest(url, method=method, formdata=args, callback=self.after_login)
```

The fill_login_form method will try its best to locate the correct form of login. And then it will return everything needed to perform a Login. If you fill in the form manually, something may be missed.